# Enter current date into a cell when another cell is changed

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a Google spreadsheet that I use to track the status of configuration information requested for an app, from a client. E.g. Text to go on a button. 
I have a column with 'Status' at the top and cells with 'List from Range' Data Validation in the rows beneath. The range used has 'With client', 'With Me', 'Completed'. I also have a column to the right which I use to manually add the date the last time the status changed. What I would like is for the date to be automatically changed to today's date when I change the status. I believe it can be done with a script but I have never used one before.

Comment: I'd also tag this with [tag:google-apps-script] - I think that's what you'd have to use.

Comment: You might look at this link: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/understanding_triggers Google Spreadsheets do support an "on edit" trigger that executes every time a spreadsheet is edited. That would be a good place to start. Also, in your spreadsheet, going "Tools > Script Editor" will give you the option of creating a new app that runs with a spreadsheet. That app will already contain code to load the particular spreadsheet that was open when you clicked "Tools > Script Editor".

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The other answer started with a good idea but unfortunately the suggested code does not work because it has many basic errors (obviously it wasn't tested ...)

So here is a version that simply works :

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var sheet      = e.source.getActiveSheet();
  var activeCell = sheet.getActiveCell();
  var col        = activeCell.getColumn();
  var row        = activeCell.getRow();
  if (col == 2 ) { // assuming status is in column 2, adapt if needed
    sheet.getRange(row, col+1).setValue(new Date()).setNumberFormat('MMM dd yyyy');// change the display format to your preference here
  }
}
```

Comment: I added this to mine to avoid overwriting a date previously set: `if (col == 1 && sheet.getRange(row, col+1).isBlank())`. I don't know if it is elegant code but it works.

Comment: How do I set a fixed Sheet? my worksheet has many tabs, I'd like to use this code just in a specific tab ... thanks!

Comment: Simply add a condition on the sheet name and return if the name doesn't match the one you want. Use sheet.getName()

Answer (score 1):

```
     column 'Status'    column 'date'
row 'List from Range'   12-08-20014
row 'Data Validation'   -----------
```

range {'With client', 'With Me', 'Completed'}

ok if you open your script editor and add the code below, replace the BOLD TERMS with relevant values.
onEdit() should not need a trigger as it is a 'special' function, unless you are sharing the sheet and need otehrs to run it with developer authority.

```
onEdit() {
  var sheet      = e.source.getActiveSheet();
  var col        = activecell.getColumn();     //  numeric value of column, ColA = 1
  var row        = activecell.getRow();        //  numeric value of row
  if (col == PUT IN THE NUMBER OF YOUR COLUMN 'Status') {
    sheet.getRange(row, col+1) = Date();
}
```

Comment: link to working example https://drive.google.com/open?id=1KXT6Lt8iULNtMlOVl7rFEMGjFjwpUQQnWo4fdbC5Gxo

Answer (score 1):

```
function onEdit(e) {
   var sheet      = e.source.getActiveSheet();
   var activeCell = sheet.getActiveCell();
   var col        = activeCell.getColumn();
   var row        = activeCell.getRow();
   if (col == 2) {
     sheet.getRange(row, 1).setValue(new Date()).setNumberFormat('dd/MM/yyyy H:m:s');
  }
}
```

Comment: You might want to explain your answer so other people learn from it.

Comment: Could someone tell me how to add time to this?