# VBA to GAS script conversion

Tags: excel, vba, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am really new to macros and stuff in both Excel and Spreadsheets. I had a friend who created this macro in Excel which does the needed job:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim day As String

    If Target.Row > 2 Then        
        day = Date
        Sheets("CFbase").Cells(Target.Row, Target.Column).Value = day
    End If

End Sub
```

In short: I need to enter a text in my first sheets and the today's date to be generated in the equivalent cell on another sheet.

I need this on order to later on use the dates for conditional formatting later on using the date to color each cell depending if it was updated today or in the last days.

Can this macro be converted to a script for spreadsheets?

Comment: A script for spreadsheets, to be run with?

Comment: Just to clarify. Are you asking if this can be ported from Excel VBA to Google Sheets Apps Scripts? I haven't worked with Google Sheets scripting, but I'm betting it could be. [It would probably look something like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25285203/enter-current-date-into-a-cell-when-another-cell-is-changed)

Comment: @JNevill I will check the thread you gave me.
Also yeah, I am trying to make  the same script working in Spreadsheets but basically I have zero knowledge how it can be done.

Comment: I'd help more, but I'm out of my element when it comes to Google Apps Scripts. I do believe 100% that the link I shared will get you 90% of the way there though. The trick will just be pointing that date output to another sheet using the defined `row` and `column` variables already present in the script. Should be pretty easy using that as a starting point.

Comment: what is the first value you enter is it a date?

Comment: The first value looks like  this "SD1234567". It's far from a date.

Comment: did the answer worked?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do something like this. The `onEdit(e)`triggers any time you add a new value.
Then you grab the value and place the actual date in the same cell in the other `sheet`. You can also add conditions if you don't wan't this code lines to execute every time.

```
function onEdit(e)
{
  // condition to make sure you are not entering value in the date sheet
  if(e.source.getActiveSheet().getName() != "CFbase" && e.range.rowStart > 2)
  {
    //grab the sheet where you wan't the date to be inserted.
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("CFbase");
    //grab the cell where the date will be inserted 
    var cell = sheet.getRange(e.range.getRow(), e.range.getColumn());
    //create the actual date
    var now = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT+1", "dd/MM/yyyy");
    //set the value of the cell with the date
    cell.setValue(now);
  }
}
```

[Here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) is documentation to properly format your `Date`.

Comment: Replaced "CFbase" with the actual name of my second sheet and tried to run the macro. Getting the following error: TypeError: Cannot read property "source" from undefined.

Comment: can you share your spreahsheet please I'll have a look at it  it will be easier please. the error comes from onEdit not the name. I guess you are trying to run onEdit from the IDE

Comment: just edited my code it works now. please avoid running onEdit directly from the IDE it won't work to debug go in the menu at  "execution script" to execute onEdit just change a value in the spreasheet

Comment: Here's a link to the sheet. Hope it helps:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1_7ZqnpMbj0oT0-wZguAZawcKGssI1edbNaV4bYtd_wk/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: After researching I found out that there isn't a good way to make cross-sheet conditional color formatting. So how can the code be changed so it just pastes the date into the cell to the right (created an empty column to under each lettered column). (I've played a bit with a copy code but couldn't manage to make the script work)

Comment: `cell = e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(e.range.getRow(), e.range.getColumn() + 1);` delete also the previous line this should do the trick

Comment: When I delete a cell from it's content it still pastes the date on the right? Is there a way to remove that? Or if I have to configure the script to work in every 2nd column, starting from A (e.g. A,C,E,G,I and so on.)

Comment: make another post please

Comment: Opened one. Take a look when you have the time. Really thank you in advance.