# GAS exclude a key to execute a macro

Tags: google-apps-script, spreadsheet

I got much help on the following script: [THREAD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52258515/vba-to-gas-script-conversion/52259699?noredirect=1#comment91490995_52259699)

Now the issue is that the script works perfectly on every cell. The thing is that I want it to not work when i use the "delete" key to clear cells. Right now If I press the "delete" key it populates the date in the 'right cell'.

```
    function onEdit(e)
    {
      // condition to make sure you are not entering value in the date sheet
      if(e.source.getActiveSheet().getName() != "Dates" && e.range.rowStart > 2)
      {
        //grab the sheet where you wan't the date to be inserted.
        var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Dates");
        //grab the cell where the date will be inserted 
        var cell = e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(e.range.getRow(), e.range.getColumn() + 1);
        //create the actual date
        var now = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT+2", "MM-dd-yyyy");
        //set the value of the cell with the date
cell.setValue(now);
      }
    }
```

The user JSmith helped me a lot here. Seeking your help again, bro. (I owe you big time, since I've never worked with GAS)

Answer (score 0):

Try this code that works for a range of a single column and one/multiple rows.

```
  function onEdit(e)
  {
    var values = e.range.getValues();
    var now = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT+2", "MM-dd-yyyy");
    var newRange = e.range.getSheet().getRange(e.range.getRow(), e.range.getColumn() + 1,e.range.getLastRow() - e.range.getRow() + 1, 1);
    values.forEach(function (el)
    {
      if (el[0])
        el[0] = now;
    });
    newRange.setValues(values);
  }
```

Comment: Tried it, it still replaces an already filled cell with the date. Dunno if I am doing something wrong.
PS: Reverted it back to the old script, if you wanna check it again.

Comment: Will try everything in a few and let you know what are the results. Thank you!

Comment: So, I believe it works fine with only one flaw. It generates the date in the next cell when the data in the cell is typed manually but if I paste it from the clipboard, it doesn't generate anything at all.

Comment: that's normal cell processing and range with multiple rows/columns don't quite work the same

Comment: Works almost perfectly (you're a demi-god). The only thing left is that again when I delete the generated date in the cell, it deletes the next (right) cell as well (with the text information I enter).
Does it need to have a 'check' if the cell is empty or sth?